# How to optimize duplicate parts in multiple methods

Tags: java, optimization

I have some old validation methods,and They all have a common part.

```
@Service
public class Validator implements IValidator {

    @Resource
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Override
    public void validA(String paramA, Long id) {

        //do some logic processing of the paramA

        Company company = companyRepository.load(id);
        //convert company to companyDto
        CompanyDto companyDto = CompanyParser.fromCompany(company);

        //do some logic
    }

    @Override
    public void validB(String paramB, Long id) {

        //do some logic processing of the paramB

        Company company = companyRepository.load(id);
        //convert company to companyDto
        CompanyDto companyDto = CompanyParser.fromCompany(company);

        //do some logic
    }

    @Override
    public void validC(String paramC, Long id) {

        //do some logic processing of the paramC

        Company company = companyRepository.load(id);
        //convert company to companyDto
        CompanyDto companyDto = CompanyParser.fromCompany(company);

        //do some logic
    }

}
```

Now, I have a new method that needs to validate a number of parameters in one go, such as:

```
    validA(paramA, id);
    validB(paramB, id);
    validC(paramC, id);
```

If the company is big， the method of CompanyParser.fromCompany(company) will take a long time.

If we don't modify the old method, are there any good ways to optimize?

Comment: What are you asking?  I only see two lines per method which perhaps could be extracted out into a common method (assuming the parameter parsing has nothing in common).

Comment: If the result of `CompanyParser.fromCompany(company)` is not changing, then consider storing in in a static or have a Singleton

Comment: @ScaryWombat  If you know what I'm asking，Could you edit it for me to make it clearer

Comment: @ScaryWombat Statics are evil and singletons may be, too. It'll work until invoked concurrently in production. But adding a simple cache to `CompanyParser.fromCompany` could do.

Comment: @maaartinus *But adding a simple cache to CompanyParser.fromCompany* and how do propose to `cache`  this?

Comment: @ScaryWombat That's simple, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45405978/581205).

Comment: @maaartinus Thanks, but based upon your earlier comment *Statics are evil* I expected to see a solution not relying on `statics`

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sure, but this is **orthogonal to caching** which you just asked for (I didn't recall our previous discussion). Moreover, my `static` are rather harmless as it's only state is the cache, which is not observable except for the timing. `+++` It's impossible to change the method to non-static when it gets called like `CompanyParser.fromCompany` and the OP didn't want to change the code. `+++` If they do, then simply 1. remove the `static` modifier, 2. pass an instance of the `CompanyParser` to the `Validator`. 3. enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, extract out the loading and conversion of a company/dto, and add an overload to take a CompanyDto instead of an id:

```
@Service
public class Validator implements IValidator {

    @Resource
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

    @Override
    public void validA(String paramA, Long id) {
        validA(paramA, loadCompanyDto(id));
    }

    private void validA(String paramA, CompanyDto companyDto) {

        //do some logic processing of the paramA

        //do some logic
    }

    private CompanyDto loadCompanyDto(Long id) {
        Company company = companyRepository.load(id);
        //convert company to companyDto
        return CompanyParser.fromCompany(company);
    }
}
```

This refactor will not change the external interface (contract) of the class, and it should continue to execute as normal (your unit tests should still pass).

Then you can create your new method:

```
public validParams(String paramA, String paramB, String paramC, Long id) {
    CompanyDto companyDto = loadCompanyDto(id);
    validA(paramA, companyDto);
    validB(paramB, companyDto);
    validC(paramC, companyDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363701/how-to-optimize-duplicate-parts-in-multiple-methods?noredirect=1#comment77772041_45363701), I have to write an answer:

```
import com.google.common.cache.*;

class CompanyParser {
    private static final LoadingCache<Company, CompanyDto> cache =
        CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(whateverSizeYouWant)
        // set more properties if needed
        .build(new CacheLoader<Company, CompanyDto>() {
            public CompanyDto load(Company company) {
                 return originalFromCompany(company);
            }
        };

    private static CompanyDto originalFromCompany(Company company) {
        ... the original non-caching code
    }

    public static CompanyDto fromCompany(Company company) {
        return cache.getUnchecked(company);
    }
}
```

Using Guava (or [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine)), caching is pretty trivial. It's fast and thread-safe and you get about everything an in-memory cache can do.

Here, it uses `equals` and `hashCode` of `Company`. If you didn't define them, it's fine as the ones inherited from `Object` work well for your use case (assuming the repository always returns the same instance for the same `id` as the name says).

Probably, a trivial single-element home-brew cache would also do, but be careful with threads.

Comment: What if the company changes

Comment: @Frank.Dai Then it returns a stale result, which is pretty wrong. Can the company change? I don't know. The OP does (I hope). There may be a possibility to add a change listener invalidating the cache or alike. I should have added a word of warning.